# Sticky Notes Windows 10 Won't Minimize

Tags: windows-10, sticky-notes

Since last week I can't minimize sticky notes.
It will minimize when I close all the notes but if even one note is open I can't minimize the app.
Did anyone experienced the same problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Clicking on the sticky notes icon on the taskbar minimizes it. Closing all notes closes the Sticky Notes app.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but it doesn't work.

Comment: Edit your question to indicate which version of Sticky Notes you have.  What version you have is partially based on what version of Windows 10 you have installed.  Sticky Notes has recieved significant features in the last 18 months, it is very likely, what you expect to happen isn't even possible.  You might want to edit your question to provide clarity what your are expecting to have happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like MS updated Sticky Notes to use the standard restore, minimize, maximize controls.

Select Sticky Notes from the Taskbar, right click on a note and the standard window control menu should appear. Although it's probably behind the note(s) displayed; so you have to move your cursor off the display to get to it.

With the standard Windows API, only one note (window) can be minimized at a time.

Comment: Thank you, but is there any other option to minimize/maximize all notes at once as it was before the update?

Answer (score 1):

If you have any Sticky Note opened, right click on it's Task bar icon and select "Hide all notes". On contrary, if you want to see all notes back, right click on Task bar icon and select "Show all notes".

Answer (score 1):

On the Sticky Notes icon on the Taskbar, Right-click on the note that is stuck in full screen and select restore.  It brought mine back to normal size.

Also, a double-click on the title bar on the note that is stuck will bring it back to normal size.

Answer (score 0):

Using command line utility "nircmd"

In DOS Shell, type below.

nircmd win min ititle "Sticky Notes"

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, the above answers didn't work, were irrelevant, or not available. However, when I moved my courser to the very top of the full screen note, the 'header' appeared, and when I clicked on an empty space there, (not on an icon or menu), the note immediately downsized, not to the task bar, but it stayed workable on my screen, in a much smaller size.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down your shift key then right-click sticky notes. This will give you the option to minimize (all) open sticky notes.

Answer (score 0):

I had what I think is the same issue -  the app itself was opening as fullscreen, with nothing to do with the single sticky notes.

**Solution**: when you hover on the app in the taskbar it shows a mini **preview** version of the window, right click on that **preview** and select the **Restore** option. That worked for me and I'm the least computer-savvy person here.

Answer (score 0):

[The resize button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k980.png)The problem is that the maximized note does not have the little square in square icon/button in the top right to resize the window.

I had 2 monitors but was only showing one. I went into display settings and told it to use 2 monitors. Then the sticky notes could be moved from one screen to the other and not be fully maximized.

However, forget about that, I discovered that if you double click on the horizontal bar at the top of the note it will resize it to a smaller size. If you double click on the bar again it will rezize it to full screen. Or you can just click on the bar of the full screen note and drag it down to resize it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).